# WINSCP File Transfer Speed

Tags: windows, linux, ftp, winscp

I'm very comfortable using WINSCP.
However, it offer very slow speed.

It shows Windows to Linux transfer speed just  250kb/s

Is there any other WINSCP alternative which offers same set of feature with better speed ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not CPU(or IO) bound on the server side ? encryption takes a lot of CPU.

Comment: Interesting, How can i check that ? I'm sorry, i'm little new to these stuff.

Comment: I'm glad you posted because WinSCP always copies around a mere 250KB/s for me as well, and I thought it was just my web host.  I always found it strange that WinSCP spins 100% CPU whenever it's transferring and feels generally unresponsive during a transfer, now I can see they are clearly related.

Comment: You should provide more info such as the WinSCP version and the protocol you're using: is it sFTP? Plain SSH? Then try with another client such as FileZilla (only supports sFTP) or command line `sftp` or `scp`.